npm ERR! ERESOLVE: Unable to Resolve Dependency Conflict in Angular Project while Updating to from ANgular14 to Angular17
I'm encountering a dependency resolution error in my Angular project when trying to install packages. The project uses Angular 17, but there seems to be a version conflict with @angular/cdk and @angular/material, which depend on an older version of Angular. The Angular Update Guide doesnt invlove any step of updating these two to verison 17.  Here are the error details:
found 0 vulnerabilities
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'c@1.1.1',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '~12.16.2' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v20.12.1', npm: '10.5.0' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN deprecated stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: please upgrade to graceful-fs 4 for compatibility with current and future versions of Node.js
npm WARN deprecated socks@1.1.10: If using 2.x branch, please upgrade to at least 2.1.6 to avoid a serious bug with socket data flow and an import issue introduced in 2.1.0
npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.3.5: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)
npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.3.4: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)
npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.3.4: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)
npm WARN deprecated superagent@0.15.7: Please upgrade to v7.0.2+ of superagent.  We have fixed numerous issues with streams, form-data, attach(), filesystem errors not bubbling up (ENOENT on attach()), and all tests are now passing.  See the releases tab for more information at <https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/releases>.
npm WARN deprecated formidable@1.0.14: Please upgrade to latest, formidable@v2 or formidable@v3!

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! While resolving: @angular/cdk@15.2.9
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@17.3.6
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"^17.3.6" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"17.3.6" from @angular/forms@17.3.6
npm ERR!     @angular/forms@"~17.3.6" from the root project
npm ERR!   4 more (@angular/platform-browser, ...)
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from @angular/cdk@15.2.9
npm ERR!   @angular/cdk@"^15.2.9" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/cdk@"15.2.9" from @angular/material@15.2.9
npm ERR!     @angular/material@"^15.2.9" from the root project
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/common@16.2.12
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from @angular/cdk@15.2.9
npm ERR!     @angular/cdk@"^15.2.9" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @angular/cdk@"15.2.9" from @angular/material@15.2.9

Attempts:
I've tried updating @angular/cdk and @angular/material to the latest versions, using .
Using --force, that works but I still dont want the erros since they might bring problems later. Also tried to upgrade to Angular Materials 17 with "ng update @angular/material" but that did not work.
How can I resolve these version conflicts effectively without risking instability in my Angular project? I would be gratefull for any help since I am very new to angular.

I resolved this updating nagular material to 16 with  ng update @angular/material@16
